# BV and continuity for $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, bounded-variation

I'm trying with this.

For $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}_+$ let  $f_{\alpha, \beta}: [0,1]$ defined as follow

$$f(x)_{\alpha,\beta}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x^{\alpha}\sin(1/x^\beta) &\mbox{if }0<x\leq1 ,\\0&\mbox{if }x=0.\end{array}\right.$$

I want to characterize  $\alpha, \beta$ susch that:

1.) $f'$ is continuous at $x=0$

2.) $f$ is of bounder variation in $[0,1]$

For the part 2.), I got that

$$f'(x)=-\beta x^{\alpha-\beta-1} \cdot \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^\beta} \right)+ \alpha x^{\alpha-1} \cdot \sin \left( \frac{1}{x^\beta} \right) $$

if $\alpha> \beta$ then $f'$ is integrable

$$ \int_0^1 |f'| = \int_0^1 \left|-\beta x^{\alpha-\beta-1} \cdot \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^\beta} \right)+ \alpha x^{\alpha-1} \cdot \sin \left( \frac{1}{x^\beta} \right)\right| dx$$
$$ \leq \int_0^1 (\beta x^{\alpha - \beta -1} +\alpha x^{\alpha-1} )dx = \beta\int_0^1 x^{\alpha- \beta -1}dx+ \alpha\int_0^1 x^{\alpha -1}dx= \frac{\beta}{\alpha - \beta} + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha}< \infty$$

At this point I don't know how to continue, I think I have to use the FTC and do some partitions to use the definition of $BV$.

For the point 1.) I'm pretty lose.